Convert a filepath from the 8.3 shortname to the fullname when the path doesn't exist
This post explains how to convert an 8.3 shortname to fullname but only works if the target file or directory exists. If I run that suggested code in Powershell 5.1 then Get-Item throws an error saying the target doesn't exist. Example
This works
$TargetPath = "8.3 shortname for file or folder that exists"
(Get-Item -LiteralPath $TargetPath).FullName

This throws doesn't exist error
$TargetPath = "8.3 shortname for file or folder that does not exist"
(Get-Item -LiteralPath $TargetPath).FullName

Is there a way to convert an 8.3 shortname to the fullname even if the path no longer exists? I'm beginning to assume no, but thought I'd ask anyway.

Windows has GetLongPathNameW and GetShortPathNameW, but if the file doesn't actually exist, there is no path to lookup. The automatically generated short path name isn't always the same, for example in the event of duplicate files and different file systems.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getlongpathnamew
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getshortpathnamew

Thanks for the clarification! I guess the answer is "not possible" then :/ Well, can't be helped!

I suppose you could write an empty temp file, and then lookup the short path for it, and assume that's your answer. But it may not be reliable across scenarios.

obviously there's no way to consistently map the huge number of long names into the tiny set of 8.3 names. The same long file name may have different short names in different folders, for example because that name was already available before this file was created in one folder. Besides, you can set the shortname randomly

That said, you shouldn't use short names nowadays. Windows have stopped generating short names for years

I'm aware, but the use case is finding the target path of .lnk shortcut files. If the shortcut path is longer than 260 characters, the ExtendedProperty('System.Link.TargetParsingPath') of New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application for that shortcut file returns the 8.3 name. If there is a better way to extract a shortcut target path that is pointing to a long path without having Powershell convert it to a shortname, I would love to use that instead.

you should update then, pwsh 7 uses InternalSymbolicLinkLinkCodeMethods.ResolvedTarget to get the target which is basically FileSystemInfo.ResolveLinkTarget(true): https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.filesysteminfo.resolvelinktarget?view=net-8.0

Thanks! The environment this will run in is going to be Windows Server 2022, and we can't update to 7 for the customer, so PS 5.1 it is unfortunately. But I will add an if($IsCoreCLR){} section and use those calls when I have the ability to! Thank you!

@TanakaSaito that ExtendedProperty('System.Link.TargetParsingPath') requirement should be in the question, because the answers would be different

I didn’t want to limit the question since shortnames can come from different places, not just shortcut targets
